# can I omit defer keyword in this case?

Tags: go, goroutine, defer-keyword

```
go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            ch <- i
        }
    }()
```

```
go func() {
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            ch <- i
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()
```

Are these two code the same? Seems the same running them and I have seen both writings.

Comment: While this contrived example happens to be functionally equivalent, [`defer`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Defer_statements) does more than just run the function as the last statement.

Comment: In the second case, if a panic happens before `defer`, the `defer` will never be called. In the first case, it will be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those 2 seem to be identical, there may be cases when they're not. That's because deferred functions are also executed if the function is panicking.

So for example if `ch` is a closed channel, sending on a closed channel will panic (see [How does a non initialized channel behave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015602/how-does-a-non-initialized-channel-behave/39016004#39016004)), and without `defer` `wg.Done()` will not be called. With `defer`, it will be. This may be very important for another goroutine calling `wg.Wait()` to get unblocked.

Another difference is that the deferred function and its arguments are evaluated when the `defer` statement is executed, in your case before the loop. If the `wg` variable would be modified e.g. after the first send, the one with `defer` would not see the new value of `wg`, the one without `defer` would see that as it's evaluated after the loop.

All in all, use `defer` when it makes sense, and even if you or someone else later end up modifying / extending the code, it will not be forgotten. Just think of an example where someone inserts a conditional `return`:

```
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        ch <- i
        if i == 3 {
            return
        }
    }
}()
```

Using `defer`, this won't be a problem, `wg.Wait()` will still be called. Without `defer`, it won't be.

See related questions:

[Proper way to release resources with defer in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617758/proper-way-to-release-resources-with-defer-in-a-loop/45620423#45620423)

[The deferred call's arguments are evaluated immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360229/the-deferred-calls-arguments-are-evaluated-immediately/51361500#51361500)